# random response from interactive broker api

Tags: java, tws

I playing with the samples provided by IB in their API, but I got absolutely (at least from what I see) random results, here some logs:

```
main (16:32:27): REQ: secDef 1
main (16:32:27): REQ: rfq 1528036347
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:27): Error id=-1 code=2104 msg=Market data farm connection is OK:usfuture
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:27): Error id=-1 code=2104 msg=Market data farm connection is OK:eufarm
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:27): Error id=-1 code=2104 msg=Market data farm connection is OK:usopt
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:27): Error id=-1 code=2104 msg=Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:27): Error id=-1 code=2106 msg=HMDS data farm connection is OK:euhmds
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:27): Error id=-1 code=2106 msg=HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:27): Error id=-1 code=2104 msg=Market data farm connection is OK:usfuture
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:27): Error id=-1 code=2104 msg=Market data farm connection is OK:eufarm
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:27): Error id=-1 code=2104 msg=Market data farm connection is OK:usopt
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:27): Error id=-1 code=2104 msg=Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:27): Error id=-1 code=2106 msg=HMDS data farm connection is OK:euhmds
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:27): Error id=-1 code=2106 msg=HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds

AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:27): tickPrice:1 field:68 (delayedLast) value:1.55
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:27): tickPrice:1 field:66 (delayedBid) value:1.51
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:27): tickPrice:1 field:67 (delayedAsk) value:1.56
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:27): tickPrice:1 field:72 (delayedHigh) value:2.1
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:27): tickPrice:1 field:73 (delayedLow) value:1.48
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:27): tickSize:1 field:74 (delayedVolume) value:161
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:27): tickPrice:1 field:75 (delayedClose) value:1.47

AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:27): Error id=1 code=10090 msg=Part of requested market data is not subscribed. Subscription-independent ticks are still active.Delayed market data is available.IBM NYSE/TOP/ALL
```

Note, that despite the `Error`, I still received the delayed prices.
Now (28 secondes later) I relaunch exactly the same sample without touching anything:

```
main (16:32:55): REQ: secDef 1
main (16:32:55): REQ: rfq 1528036375
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:55): Error id=-1 code=2104 msg=Market data farm connection is OK:usfuture
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:55): Error id=-1 code=2104 msg=Market data farm connection is OK:eufarm
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:55): Error id=-1 code=2104 msg=Market data farm connection is OK:usopt
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:55): Error id=-1 code=2104 msg=Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:55): Error id=-1 code=2106 msg=HMDS data farm connection is OK:euhmds
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:55): Error id=-1 code=2106 msg=HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:55): Error id=-1 code=2104 msg=Market data farm connection is OK:usfuture
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:55): Error id=-1 code=2104 msg=Market data farm connection is OK:eufarm
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:55): Error id=-1 code=2104 msg=Market data farm connection is OK:usopt
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:55): Error id=-1 code=2104 msg=Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:55): Error id=-1 code=2106 msg=HMDS data farm connection is OK:euhmds
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:55): Error id=-1 code=2106 msg=HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds
AWT-EventQueue-0 (16:32:55): Error id=1 code=10090 msg=Part of requested market data is not subscribed. Subscription-independent ticks are still active.Delayed market data is available.IBM NYSE/TOP/ALL
```

Now I am not receiving any prices! Here is how the call itself looks like:

```
client().reqMarketDataType(3); //delayed prices
client().reqMktData(1,contract,"",true, null);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The errors are just informational, not actual errors.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using the [Ib_insync](https://github.com/erdewit/ib_insync/) sdk:

````
ib = IB()
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, clientId=1)

c = Contract(conId=292579214)

ib.qualifyContracts(c)
ib.reqMarketDataType(3)
ticker = ib.reqTickers(c)
print(ticker)
for obj in ticker:
    print("--->{}<------".format(obj.ask))```
````

Maybe this will help someone else...